# apache ab in for loop

Tags: bash, unix, apachebench

I'd like to run apache ab test more times with different parameters that will be stored in an array.
eg.:

```
$array {10,50,100,500,1000}
for $i in $array
ab -A name:pass -n $i -c $i http://www.google.com/.... > file_$i.txt
```

While it's important that, to begin the i-th test, the previous test has to be finished.

Comment: OK...and what's the problem (other than some incorrectly syntaxed shell script)?

Comment: I agree with @drysdam. You're asking us to guess what your problem is.  Questions in the form of 1. I have this input, 2. I want this output. 3. (but) I'm getting this output, 4. with this code .... {code here} .... have a much better chance of getting a reasonable response in a reasonable amount of time ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @drysdam sorry I didn't explicitly formulate the problem, but you're right it's just syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off the top of my head (untested)

```
array=(10 50 100 500 1000)
for i in ${array[@]}; do
  ab -A name:pass -n $i -c $i http://www.google.com/.... > file_$i.txt
done
```